# identifierForVendor changed when updating new version of app on older version. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have downloaded my app version 1.8.8 from Appstore and after that i have update this app by downloading a new version of app from Testflight.
Then the issue begins according to the Apple Documentation identifierForVendor will not change when updating app.
But here my app's identifierForVendor changed after updation due to which user logged out from app.

I have tried for Testflight builds i.e, downloaded old build 1.8.8 from Testflight and logged in after that update it from newer version available on Testflight and it's working fine. But if i download the Appstore build and then update the build provided on Testflight then identifierForVendor changed and user logged out.

User shouldn't logout if updating the app from Testflight with same environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try read apple's documentation more carefully:

> Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store.
>   If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise
>   apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is
>   calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to
>   be in reverse-DNS format.

Try download old version from Appstore and new version from Appstore: result will be the same. It's not big deal the version from appstore and from tesflight have different identifiers for vendor.